# При выводе одни нули

Tags: c++

Никак не могу найти ошибку в коде на C++ - результаты ни с того, ни с сего выдает по нулям (задача - распределить m вещей туристам(n) поровну).

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    int a, i, j, n, m, minrazid;
    float k, c, b, minraz;
    float tmp;
    float q;
    bool ami;

    printf("Введите кол-во туристов - n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("Введите кол-во вещей - n");
    scanf("%d", &m);

    float M[m];
    float N[n];
    float z[m];

    for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        M[i] = 0;
        z[i] = 0; //Зануляем массивы
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        N[i] = 0;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        printf("Введите вес вещи номер %dn", i + 1);
        scanf("%f", &M[i]);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
        k += M[i];

    k = k / n; //Находим долю веса на туриста


    /*for (i = 0; i <= m - 1; i++)
        for (j = 0; j <= m - 1; j++)
            if (M[j] < M[j + 1]) { //Сортировка
                tmp = M[j];
                M[j] = M[j + 1];
                M[j + 1] = tmp;
            }*/



    a = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
        if (M[i] > k) {
            N[a] = M[i];
            M[i] = 0;
            ++a;
        } //Даем большие вещи (больше среднего арифметического k) по одной на нос


    b = 0;


    while (q != 0) //Даем остальные вещи
    {

        for (i = a; i < n; i++) {
          ischo:
            minraz = 1000000; //Задаем переменную для минимальной разницы между k и весом мешка в данный момент
            for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {
                b = k - N[i];
                z[j] = b - M[j]; //Считаем сколько осталось каждому туристу до среднего арифметического k с вещью j
            }
            ami = false;        //см. строку 66
            for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {
                if (z[j] >= 0 && minraz > z[j]) {
                    minraz = z[j];
                    minrazid = j //Находим самый подходящий предмет
                    ami = true;
                }
            } //если true, то ищем еще предметы для этого туриста     
            N[i] += M[minrazid];
            M[minrazid] = 0;
            if (ami = true)
                goto ischo;
        }



        q = 0; //Зануляем q (см. строки 75 и 53)

        for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            q += M[i];
        } //Смотрим остались ли еще вещи 
    }


    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("Вес вещей для туриста номер %dn", i + 1);
        printf("%fn", N[i]);
    }


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вот глянул, увидел заминусовано, прочитал. 

Честно признаюсь, искать логическую ошибку в этой задачке лень.


Но абсолютно не понял за что минус ? Кто-нибудь может объяснить ?

Comment: Проще всего вывести результаты промежуточных вычислений, тогда и найдете свой баг.

Comment: дошел глазами до сортировки. Классическую сортировку пузырьком не смогли правильно написать... Там выход за пределы массива. Не удивлюсь, если он нахватал нулей или другого мусора.

Comment: avp, я сам уже столько раз проверял и по-разному задачу переписывал, и все время какая-нибудь хрень вместо ответа правильного. Может у gcc или самого языка есть какие-нибудь специфические особенности, о которых я не знаю?

Answer (score 2):

Массив определённый как M[m] имеет нумерацию от 0..m-1, у вас M[j+1] при максимальном значении становиться M[m] что уже за диапазоном, и, скорее всего, ссылаеться на массив N что и приводит к порче данных и неправильной работе алгоритма.

```
for (i = 0; i <= m - 1; i++)
        for (j = 0; j <= m - 1; j++)
            if (M[j] < M[j + 1]) { //Сортировка
                tmp = M[j];
                M[j] = M[j + 1];
                M[j + 1] = tmp;
            }
```

Comment: Сортировку я убрал (она не нужна, просто так добавил), но ответ не изменился.